# Extending UIKit class with Swift breaks Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've encountered the weirdest bug. When you extend some UIKit class with Swift to implement a protocol, like extending `UIButton` to implement protocol `SomeProtocol` (yes, it can even be empty):

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
}

extension UIButton: SomeProtocol {
}
```

Context menu in IB when right-clicking on a UIButton object will loose much of its options:

[image: With extension]

Should I remove that extension, I'll get this:

[image: Without extension]

Did anyone encountered anything similar? Is there a solution?

This happens both with Xcode 6.1.1 and Xcode 6.3 Beta 1. It does not matter where you define extension - in a project's source file or in a framework as s subproject.

I tried declaring protocol as

```
@objc protocol SomeProtocol
@objc protocol SomeProtocol: class
protocol SomeProtocol: class
```

but none work.

Comment: Have you tried to use 'NSObjectProtocol'?

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be that you're declaring a pure Swift protocol which you use to extend an ObjC class.
Try declaring the protocol as `@objc protocol SomeProtocol {` or maybe even forcing it to be class-only like `protocol SomeProtocol: class {`.

Comment: I believe we're out of luck here then. What's probably happening is that IB only supports ObjC features and in ObjC you can't extend a class with a protocol so IB freaks out in this case. This is only a guess though and you might have better luck asking on Apple Developer forums or even just file a bug and see what Apple people say.

Comment: Terrible. Filed bug 19799266.

Comment: Try using something like http://www.quickradar.com so it posts a duplicate to OpenRadar and I can then also file this big, might get more attention that way.